# Thymeleaf : Call Java function in JavaScript Click listener

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

So I have this controller class with some getters and setters and a function:

```
@Controller
public class Hotels{
    public Hotels(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Hotels(String name, String price, String longitude, String latitude, String URL, String photoURL) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.URL = URL;
        PhotoURL = photoURL;
    }

    public Hotels() {
    }

    public List<Hotels> returnHotels(String city) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        double[] lnglat = new double[2];
        MapController controller = new MapController();
        for (int i = 0; i <controller.coolLocations().size(); i++) {
            if(controller.coolLocations().get(i).getDescription().equals(city)){
                lnglat = controller.coolLocations().get(i).getLnglat();
            }
        }
       
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create("https://booking-com.p.rapidapi.com/v1/hotels/search-by-coordinates?order_by=popularity&adults_number=2&units=metric&room_number=1&checkout_date=2022-11-15&filter_by_currency=RON&locale=en-gb&checkin_date=2022-11-12&latitude="+lnglat[1]+"&longitude="+lnglat[0]))
            .header("X-RapidAPI-Key", "myKey")
            .header("X-RapidAPI-Host", "booking-com.p.rapidapi.com")
            .method("GET", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody())
            .build();
        HttpResponse<String> response = HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        
       
        String[] datasplit = response.body().split("\"");
        String url = "";
        String hotel_name = "";
        String latitude = "";
        String longitude = "";
        String gross_price= "";
        String main_photo_url= "";
        for (int i = 0; i < datasplit.length; i++) {
            if (datasplit[i].equals("url")) url = datasplit[i+2];
            if (datasplit[i].equals("hotel_name")) hotel_name = datasplit[i+2];
            if (datasplit[i].equals("latitude")) latitude = datasplit[i+1].substring(1).replace(',',' ');
            if (datasplit[i].equals("longitude")) longitude = datasplit[i+1].substring(1).replace(',',' ');
            if ((datasplit[i].equals("gross_amount_hotel_currency") && datasplit[i+1].equals(":{") && datasplit[i+2].equals("value"))) gross_price = datasplit[i+3].substring(1).replace('}',' ').replace(',',' ');
            if ((datasplit[i].equals("gross_amount_hotel_currency") && datasplit[i+1].equals(":{") && datasplit[i+2].equals("currency") && datasplit[i+3].equals(":") && datasplit[i+4].equals("EUR")&& datasplit[i+5].equals(",") && datasplit[i+6].equals("value"))) gross_price = datasplit[i+7].substring(1).replace('}',' ').replace(',',' ');
            if (datasplit[i].equals("max_photo_url")) main_photo_url = datasplit[i+2];
            if(datasplit[i].equals("max_1440_photo_url"))hotelsList.add(new Hotels(hotel_name, gross_price, longitude, latitude, url, main_photo_url));
        }
        hotelsList.forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println(city);
        return hotelsList;
    }
}
```

And this is my get Mapping :

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String homePage(Model model) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    model.addAttribute("returnHotels", new Hotels());
    return "home";
}
```

And a JavaScript on click listener :

```
marker.getElement().addEventListener('click', function () {
const city = location.description;
});
```

I want inside the JS click listener to call my **returnHotels** function with the **const city** as my parameter. Is it possible?
PS : I've deleted the class variables so the site let me post

Comment: One approach: You can use an Ajax `GET` call in your JS event function, to hit a new endpoint in your Spring controller. That endpoint can receive the `city` parameter and call whatever Java you want. It can return results as JSON from the Ajax call.

Comment: Side note: This has nothing to do with Thymeleaf - remember that by the time the web page has been displayed, there is no more Thymeleaf - it has been replaced by regular HTML. So, the question is more about JavaScript (or using a standard HTML form submission).